# Is there a method to show a table after pressing on the button?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello i am new on ruby on rails.I am trying to build a page that have a date field, and after choosing a specific date, i want to generate a table that shows reports of this date select.

controllers/reports_controller.rb

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def test
        @chosen_date = params[:report_date]

        @incoming_messages = Message.where("inbound = 't' and created_at like '" + @chosen_date + "%'").count
        @total_chats = Message.where("created_at like '" + @chosen_date + "%'").distinct.count(:phone_number)
        @enrollment_by_andi = Enrollment.where("created_at like '" + @chosen_date + "%' and created_by = 'ANDI'").count
        @enrollment_by_agent = Enrollment.where("created_at like '" + @chosen_date + "%' and created_by <> 'ANDI'").count
        @sent_by_andi = Message.where("created_by = 'ANDI' and created_at like '" + @chosen_date + "%'").count
        @sent_by_agents = Message.where("inbound = 'f' and created_by <> 'ANDI' and created_at like '" + @chosen_date + "%'").count
        @unread_messages = Message.where("created_at like '" + @chosen_date + "%' and is_read = 'f'").distinct.count(:phone_number)

    end
end
```

views/reports/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Reports</h1>

<%= form_tag(reports_test_path,:method => "post") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:report_date,"Choose a Date") %>
    <%= date_field_tag(:report_date)%>
    <%= button_tag "Submit"%>
<% end %>
```

table i want to generate:

```
<table>
    <th>
        <td>Incoming Messages</td>
        <td>Total Chats</td>
        <td>Enrollment By Andi</td>
        <td>Enrollment By Agent</td>
        <td>Sent By Andi</td>
        <td>Sent By Agents</td>
        <td>Unread Messages</td>
    </th>
    <tr>
        <td><%= @incoming_messages %></td>
        <td><%= @total_chats %></td>
        <td><%= @enrollment_by_andi %></td>
        <td><%= @enrollment_by_agent %></td>
        <td><%= @sent_by_andi %></td>
        <td><%= @sent_by_agents %></td>
        <td><%= @unread_messages %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Below is the image of the page:

[image]

Anyone can help me to find a method to generate a table under the date field when i press the button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AJAX which goes really well with rails and is really decent. For this follow the following steps -

1. First create a partial `_report_table.html.erb`. You have a little problem in the table. So paste the below table html in the partial -

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Incoming Messages</th>
     <th>Total Chats</th>
     <th>Enrollment By Andi</th>
     <th>Enrollment By Agent</th>
     <th>Sent By Andi</th>
     <th>Sent By Agents</th>
     <th>Unread Messages</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><%= @incoming_messages %></td>
     <td><%= @total_chats %></td>
     <td><%= @enrollment_by_andi %></td>
     <td><%= @enrollment_by_agent %></td>
     <td><%= @sent_by_andi %></td>
     <td><%= @sent_by_agents %></td>
     <td><%= @unread_messages %></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

2. create a js file as `test.js.erb` as your post method name is test which puts the table html in a div in `index.html.erb`

```
$('#report_table').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'report_table') %>");
```

3. add a div with report_table id in index.html.erb after the form

`<div id="report_table"></div>`

4. Add remote true in the form

`form_tag(reports_test_path,:method => "post",:remote=>true)`

5. add return in the test method which will render the required js file

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

That should do it. Please let me know if you have any connfusion

Comment: Thank you, i did exactly as you said and it works very well

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the form by ajax by setting `remote: true` on the form tag:

```
<%= form_tag(reports_test_path,:method => "post", remote: true) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:report_date,"Choose a Date") %>
  <%= date_field_tag(:report_date)%>
  <%= button_tag "Submit"%>
<% end %>
```

You then create a corresponding `app/views/reports/test.js.erb view file that generates the actual JavaScript code that will be sent and executed on the client side.

You can put the table in a partial, say `app/views/reports/_table.html.erb` and render it in the javascript:

```
  var tableContainer = document.getElementById(...);
  tableContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<%= j render partial: "/reports/table" %>');
```

If you're not too familiar working with ajax and javascript, check out the [Ruby on Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements)

Comment: I don't think that the issue is about AJAX requests and dynamic content addition into the document. Server-side rendering is totally fine for this case

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with server-side rendering

Add a template file with the following content:

views/reports/test.html.erb

```
<h1>Reports</h1>

<%# The date field from the index.html %>
<%= form_tag(reports_test_path,:method => "post") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:report_date,"Choose a Date") %>
    <%= date_field_tag(:report_date)%>
    <%= button_tag "Submit"%>
<% end %>

<%# the new content %>
<table>
    <th>
        <td>Incoming Messages</td>
        <td>Total Chats</td>
        <td>Enrollment By Andi</td>
        <td>Enrollment By Agent</td>
        <td>Sent By Andi</td>
        <td>Sent By Agents</td>
        <td>Unread Messages</td>
    </th>
    <tr>
        <td><%= @incoming_messages %></td>
        <td><%= @total_chats %></td>
        <td><%= @enrollment_by_andi %></td>
        <td><%= @enrollment_by_agent %></td>
        <td><%= @sent_by_andi %></td>
        <td><%= @sent_by_agents %></td>
        <td><%= @unread_messages %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You could reduce the repetition later on with partials and such, but that is not so important right now.

The more important problem is that your queries at least look you could do SQL injection with them (google for blog posts about "SQL injection active record rails"). Familiarize yourself with the ActiveRecord guides a bit more, things are more safe when you do it like this:

```rb
@chosen_date = Date.parse params[:report_date]

@incoming_messages = Message.where(inbound: 't').where(created_at: @chosen_date).count
```

Plus you don't need to write the SQL on your own.

Chaining the `.where()` leads to an `AND` in SQL and passing Date and Time objects (and Ranges) into the `where()` methods are improvements in the Rails releases from the later years

Comment: Thank you for telling me about SQL injections.